# Evoluent mouse user buttons assigned to cut/copy/paste don't work through Windows Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, mouse

I have my Evoluent mouse user buttons assigned for cut/copy/paste (which saves a ton of time).  This works great on my Windows 7 Pro desktop, and my other Evoluent mouse on my Win7 Pro laptop at work.

But when I do a Remote Desktop session from laptop at work to desktop at home, OR at home from desktop to laptop, mouse's cut/copy/paste buttons result in a small 'v' instead.  ctrl-c/v/x works okay.  Mouse's right-click button, for context menu cut/copy/paste, works okay.

UPDATE:
I upgraded Evoluent mouse manager at both desktop and laptop to v5.5.
Now, laptop through Remote Desktop connection to desktop works okay,
but desktop through RD to laptop still fails, with same symptom as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote Desktop configuration > Local Res.. tab > Keyboard > Apply Windows key comb.. = "On this computer"